# How to create product template?

Tags: theming, commerce

[image]

Please see the red box. In Magento there is a feature where i can create Product Templates - templates can be created for products with different fields.

I know i can create Content Types for this, but i felt that will make too many Content Types. Is there another work around this so that it's like Magento? Is there a module for it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal Commerce you can just make product types and it will generate product displays (content types) meant for building the presentation. The product type holds all the meta data about the product itself.

Answer (score -1):

With different fields for each template you have two ways:

1. different content types
2. one (maybe extreme large) content type with all fields, and then hide unused fields, depends on template choosen (template options in taxonomy list). You can use conditional fields module:
   https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields
   still not ready for drupal 8, but as you can see issue, will be ported soon. If not, you can write own module or use some ugly javascript to hide fields.